# How do you disable error tracking in Jsoup's Tokeniser?

Tags: java, jsoup

**Note:** This question refers to `Jsoup 1.6.1`

I need to parse several documents using Jsoup, but I have noticed the memory builds up after some time. Using heap dumps and a memory analyzer, I have tracked down the problem to Jsoup's `Tokeniser` class, which stores an `ArrayList` of `ParseError`'s. In the heap dump, there were over 5 million of `ParseError` objects stored, at 56 bytes each.

Looking at the source code, I noticed a variable in `org.jsoup.parser.Tokeniser` which allows error tracking to be turned off. Following the flow of the calls, I can not see any call to turn it off, despite there being a method to do so. The class not being public, I am forced to modify the source code and build it from source.

Is there a method I can call or a property I can set to effectively disable error tracking in the `Tokeniser` without having to modify the source code?

Comment: I did modify the source code because I'm in a production environment, so I needed this to work as soon as possible. I am still curious as to if this is possible without modifying the source code.

Comment: can you show the code you use to do the parsing ?

Comment: Same as on http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string but with different data, of course.

Comment: Looking at the source code I see that everything you mentioned is correct. There is no method that you can directly call to turn off error tracking and you must modify the source code. Yet, it is probably worth opening an issue for Jsoup staff. There is no use of the errors list except for adding errors to it. It looks this was only used for internal debugging in the class Tokeniser and they forgot to turn off the boolean variable that controls error logging before moving the code to production. (in the class TreeBuilder they do turn it off).

Comment: Turning it off in the source code itself cut down on a lot of memory and made parsing seem faster, although I do not have numbers, it only feels faster. The problem in the first place was not with Jsoup, but rather with the data. Somebody sent an image claiming it is an HTML document. 5 million pixels, 5 million `ParseError` objects. ;)

Comment: :)))))))))  this is great. an example how a bug leads to the discovery of another another. I hope you won't get a video file next time :) Happy it got sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue is not caused by Jsoup. The file it was trying to parse was not an HTML file but an image. Since Jsoup is not intended to check if it has the right type of file and relies on the programmer to check that in the first place, the answer to this question is **in Jsoup 1.6.1, you can not unless you modify the source code**. Turning off error tracking in Jsoup's `Tokeniser` class did reduce memory usage and improve speed a little (due to not inserting many elements in an `ArrayList`), but modifying the source code is not recommended. If you ever encounter this problem, check your own code first. ;)